# Do A Limit on the Output of a Function in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math

I know you can probably do a limit of a mathematical operation, say the limit of n + 1 as n approaches infinity, but can I do the limit of a function? For instances the limit of dividing to Fibonacci numbers as their index (and value) gets greater, approaching infinity? For example

`lim(func, start, approach)`

I have looked at sympy, and it is either not possible or I don't know how to pass a symbol argument as an integer. Eg:

`iters = Symbol("iters")
print limit(main(iters),iters,0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't need to make my integer a symbol.
The code above works.